# Accedently pressed Verify integrety of game cache and it deleted all my files in terraria how can I recover them.

Tags: steam, terraria

My computer gave an notification saying that my memory was clouding up (I have 1tb added up with my two discs) so I tried everything to send all the files how my :c drive to my :E drive but I couldn't (Please tell me how to move the files if you can also) That's when I accidently clicked Verify integrity of game cache and it deleted everything I did so far including my stuff and my worlds plz tell me how to recover my stuff.

Comment: Using Steam's "verify integrity" option doesn't normally destroy saved games, but doing something like sending all your files from C: to E: easily could.

Comment: Terraria stores its worlds under `C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\My Games\Terraria`. If you moved any of these folders to your E: drive you should put them back exactly where they were.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem was not caused by Steam's "Verify Integrity of Game Cache" option.  It was most likely caused by moving the unspecified files from your C: to E:.

You should reverse what you did in the previous step.